# How does l_bfgs optimization method approximate the gradient

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm using scipy's **[fmin_l_bfgs_b](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html)** optimization method on a 2-dimensional function available as a black box. Gradients cannot be evaluated directly, so I'm asking the method to approximate the gradients by setting `approx_grad = True`.

**I want to know how the approximate gradients are computed.** My guess is that at each point, for each dimension, gradient is approximated by forward difference. So for each point in N dimensions, N evaluations are made to get the partial derivatives. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jacobian approximation is done with [scipy.optimize.approx_fprime](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c254b4ff5def78c2a5e2d9decbd35882a2f0f650/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L549) function, [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html):

> ```
>         f(xk[i] + epsilon[i]) - f(xk[i])
> f'[i] = ---------------------------------
>                    epsilon[i]
> ```

Where epsilon is a paramether to fmin_l_bfgs_b

> epsilon : float
>
> Step size used when `approx_grad` is True, for numerically calculating the gradient

Comment: Thanks for the links. It seems my guess is correct. N function evaluations are made at each point to get the gradient, where N is the number of dimensions(size of vector x)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how scipy does it particularly. A popular approach is to calculate them as follows:

(f(x+e)-f(x-e)/(2*e) (apparently here no LaTex supported)

This gives you accuracy up to quadratic terms (just calculate Taylor expansion for each term and substract them)